# currentlyFocusedField is deprecated and will be removed in a future release when using TextInput prop "secureTextEntry"

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm using expo managed workflow for my app and this is my expo info:

```
Expo CLI 3.27.13 environment info:
System:
  OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
  Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
  Node: 10.15.3 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node
  Yarn: 1.22.5 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
  npm: 6.14.5 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/npm
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms: iOS 12.1, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.1, watchOS 5.1
IDEs:
  Xcode: 10.1/10B61 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
  expo: ^39.0.0 => 39.0.3 
  react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
  react-dom: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
  react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.0.tar.gz => 0.63.2 
  react-native-web: ~0.13.7 => 0.13.14 
npmGlobalPackages:
  expo-cli: 3.27.13
Expo Workflow: managed
```

I'm using react-native's TextInput and when I add a prop **secureTextEntry** I'm getting this message:

> currentlyFocusedField is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use currentlyFocusedInput

Does anyone know what's causing the problem because I'm not able to figure it out...

Here is my package.json file with dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
"@expo/spawn-async": "^1.5.0",
"@hookform/resolvers": "^0.1.1",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.9.2",
"@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.2.18",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.5",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.2",
"add": "^2.0.6",
"axios": "^0.19.2",
"card-validator": "^8.0.0",
"expo": "^39.0.0",
"expo-asset": "~8.2.0",
"expo-constants": "~9.2.0",
"expo-facebook": "~9.0.0",
"expo-file-system": "~9.2.0",
"expo-font": "~8.3.0",
"expo-google-app-auth": "^8.1.0",
"expo-location": "~9.0.0",
"expo-media-library": "~9.2.1",
"expo-notifications": "~0.7.2",
"expo-permissions": "~9.3.0",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
"jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.20",
"lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
"metro-config": "^0.59.0",
"moment": "^2.26.0",
"prop-types": "^15.7.2",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-dom": "16.13.1",
"react-hook-form": "^6.8.6",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.2",
"react-native-collapsible": "^1.5.3",
"react-native-dropdownalert": "^4.2.1",
"react-native-elements": "^2.0.0",
"react-native-exception-handler": "^2.10.8",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.7.0",
"react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.2",
"react-native-map-clustering": "^3.3.9",
"react-native-maps": "0.27.1",
"react-native-maps-directions": "^1.8.0",
"react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
"react-native-material-textfield": "^0.16.1",
"react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
"react-native-paper": "^3.9.0",
"react-native-phone-call": "^1.0.9",
"react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
"react-native-redash": "^15.1.2",
"react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.1",
"react-native-restart": "^0.0.15",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.4",
"react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
"react-native-screens": "~2.10.1",
"react-native-scroll-into-view": "^1.0.3",
"react-native-skeleton-content": "^1.0.20",
"react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.5.0",
"react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
"react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
"react-native-tab-view": "^2.14.2",
"react-native-web": "~0.13.7",
"react-native-webview": "10.7.0",
"react-redux": "^7.2.0",
"reanimated-bottom-sheet": "^1.0.0-alpha.20",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux-axios-middleware": "^4.0.1",
"sentry-expo": "^2.1.2",
"styled-components": "^5.1.0",
"yarn": "^1.22.5",
"yup": "^0.28.5"
```

},

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^8.3.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was in the "keyboard-aware-scroll-view" package and here is the comment that actually fixed my issue: **https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/issues/440#issuecomment-699653218**